# download a file c++ linux GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, download

I want to download all information which i see then i open this URL
http://api.worldoftanks.eu/2.0/clan/info/?application_id=d0a293dc77667c9328783d489c8cef73&clan_id=500030916, but my problem is my IDE do not support the curl libs.
I have tried `fopen` but it didn't work.

I work under Linux Ubuntu 13.10, 
IDE: Code::Blocks13.12,
compiler: GNU GCC.

sorry I'm bad in english and C++ for normal i work in LabView or C#

Comment: Libraries are not supported (or unsupported) by IDEs (which are mostly editors, you could use `emacs` & `make`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This obviously depend on what IDE you want to get it working with. However I would strongly recommend that you use a nice high level C++ library such as this one:

http://cpp-netlib.org/

You'll then need to get you're IDE to recognise the location of the header files, and include any necessary libs.

From the doc, http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/index.html, it should be as simple as:

```
using namespace boost::network;
using namespace boost::network::http;

client::request request_(your_url);
request_ << header("Connection", "close");
client client_;
client::response response_ = client_.get(request_);
std::string body_ = body(response_);
```

*EDIT: edit, whilst I am here I would strongly recommend leaning how to compile and link programs using libraries from the commandline and with hand written makefiles, doing so once will give you a better understanding on what actually going on and therefore your IDE will be less of a black box (this is advice, not a part of the answer).*